# Vim match using alternation operator | without capturing group

Tags: vim

I have a vimscript that gets a list of matches from a string passed from the vim commandline. A part of the string has a pattern like `some-word`. The following output summarizes the problem:

`echo matchlist("some-word", escape('(\w|-)+', '()+|'))
" => ['some-word', 'd', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`

I understand that `'d'` is due to the capturing group. I tried using `[\w|-]` but that wont work. I found that one way to avoid this would be to use a non capturing group `\%(\w|-)`, but it seems like adding more code. Does vim not have a solution like `[]` in perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim DOES support "collections" like in Perl, using the same [..] syntax. Even in Perl, you DON'T put the | inside the collection, unless you want to match a literal | character.

But, special characters like \w are NOT supported in [..] groups in Vim. Instead, you would use character classes like [:alpha:] or [:alnum:].

So in your specific case, you probably want: `[-[:alnum:]_]\+`

This includes '-', '_', numbers, and letters. See `:help /[` in Vim for more details.

Comment: “Also, in Vim + is not magic by itself. You need a backslash to make it special.”: this is the reason why regex is wrapped in a `escape()` call. `+` is present in the second argument to `escape()`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I saw Ingo's answer. I'll take that out. It's never occurred to me to build a pattern that way with escape() (because \v is better) so it didn't even register what was going on there.

Comment: This does explain the way to solve the problem in VimL using `[]`.

Answer (score 13):

The syntax for a non-capturing group in Vim is `\%(...\)`, and you should use that if you don't want to capture the match. That this can be expressed in a better / shorter way in other regular expression dialects (like Perl's) is irrelevant.

If you are just not interested in all / some capturing groups, you can also use `matchstr()` / *List slicing*, e.g. `matchlist(...)[0:1]`.

Another note: Your use of `escape()` to simplify some regular expression atoms is unconventional. If you want to avoid most backslashes, you can just switch to *very magic mode* by prepending `\v` to the regular expression; see `:help /\v`. The resulting regexp would be `\v(\w|-)+`.

Comment: According to the help with `\v` you must also escape `-`: “Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.”: `-` is not listed here, neither is a space, quotes and a forward slash (which are also common to come unescaped, but currently keep their meaning in all regex modes).