# how to non-capturing search and replace in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to learn how to use regex with vim, and I'm currently trying to do a search and replace. I have something like this:

```
aaaaaaa&sometext&...
aaaaaaaanothertext
```

(the `a`s are actually whitespace at the beginning of the line, that I don't know how to print that here)

And I want to replace the first occurence of `&` with `& &`, and keep everyting else as is. I'm using `\%(...\)` for non-capturing patterns, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291445/vim-match-using-alternation-operator-without-capturing-group/19291981#19291981), but the `a` pattern is still captured. I'm using `:%s/\%(^a*\)&/& &/gc`, and I get:

```
aaaaaaaa& aaaaaaaa&sometext&...
aaaaaaaaanothertext
```

I don't get why. I've also tried the replace with groups, as in `:%s/\%(^a*\)\(&\)/\1 \1/gc`, but then I get:

```
& &sometext&...
aaaaaaaanothertext
```

So, it seems the group is indeed being ignored for the group handling (since the first group is on the search pattern is `&`), but is still captured on the search pattern.

So, long story short, which replace command do I have to use to go from:

```
aaaaaaa&sometext&...
```

to:

```
aaaaaaa& &sometext&...
```

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Non-capturing" doesn't mean what you think it means. The only difference between `\(...\)` and `\%(...\)` is whether or not the subexpression is saved to `\1`, `\2`... It will still include the matched content in the match.

You wanted `\@<=` (`:help \@<=`):

```
:s/\(^a*\)\@<=&/\& \&/g
```

Answer (score 6):

> I want to replace the first occurrence of `&` with `& &`, and keep
>   everything else as is

Use a substitution command:

```
:s/&/& &/
```

Another tip: Vim by default treats `(` as a literal character, rather than the start of a group.

Use [`very magic`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) mode if you want your regex to act more like traditional (Perl) regex.

An easy way to specify `very magic` mode is to start your regex with `\v`:

```
" this is a no-op
:s/\v(this is grouped)/\1/
```

EDIT: this answer works, but please see @heijp06's very relevant comment below (I wasn't aware that the `&` character had a special meaning).

Comment pasted here:

> It is actually somewhat nontrivial why this answer is correct. An & in
>   the replacement part of a substitution means that what was matched by
>   the pattern in this case that was an & so the end effect is correct.

Comment: Nice, thanks. But I would still like to learn how to use non-capturing groups. Can it be done like that? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried your examples using `very magic` mode? Or alternately, escape your `(` and `)`?

Comment: My `(` and `)` in the examples I gave above are escaped. The `\%(` and `\)` are how I start the groups and are not trying to be matched by the vim regex engine.

I have tried with `very magic`, but got similar results: I try `:%s/\v(^a*)(\&)/\1 \1/c` and get `aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaasometext&...
`.

Comment: I found a satisfying way to do it: `:s/\v(^a*)(\&)/\1\2 \2/c`. Instead of throwing out the first group, I reuse it in the replace pattern. It does not use non-capturing groups however. I have tried with the perl non-capturing group pattern `(?:...)`, but I get an error from vim.

Comment: With the vim pattern syntax, to do the replacement with (only capturing) groups, the search pattern would be: `:%s/\(^a*\)\(&\)/\1\2 \2/c`.

Comment: It is actually somewhat nontrivial why this answer is correct. An `&` in the replacement part of a substitution means *that what was matched by the pattern* in this case that was an `&` so the end effect is correct.

Comment: With the vim pattern syntax, to do the replacement using non-capturing groups, the search pattern would be: `:s/\%(^a*\)&/& \&/`. Thanks @heijp06

Comment: You may want to add the comment to the answer, since comments can be erased/moved to chat, or (as in this case) users change their names and it becomes more difficult to find the comment mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Typically in search and replace, it's sufficient for the substitute to completely replace the search. In this case, your search will include things you don't want to replace.

Vim has helpful patterns to define the start and end of a match: `\zs` and `\ze`. You can place `\zs` anywhere in the search, vim will only match after the start. You can use both to say, find this specific line and only replace a part of it.

And the solution:

`:%s:^[^&]*\zs&:& &:c`

- `%s`: Look at every line in the file
- `^[^&]*`: From the beginning of the line, there should be zero or more **not** `&`
- `\zs&`: The match to replace is a single `&`
- `& &`: Replace the match with two `&`
- `c`: Perform each substitution interactively in-case I suck at regex